# How to partial match response in the artillery tool?

Tags: websocket, load-testing, artillery

I am using artillery tool for websocket testing. The problem I am facing is with response. After emitting data to the channel that I am testing, we always get different data. As artillery's Response block tries to match completely with the actual response from the channel (i.e It doesn't match partially) , I am always getting a error 'data is not valid: 1'. How to match partially the response?

Answer (score 1):

Below response code is working.

```
{
  "response": {
    "channel": "channel1",
    "match": [
      {
        "json": "$.Id",
        "value": "test_101"
      },
      {
        "json": "$.param1",
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "json": "$.param2",
        "value": "XXX"
      },
      {
        "json": "$.param3",
        "value": "100"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```